# How to mock a default list in python

Tags: python, python-mock

I have something like this:

abc.py

```
DEFAULT_PATTERN = ['abc','dfg']
```

def.py

```
checkName(name):
   if not [pattern for pattern in DEFAULT_PATTERN if pattern in name]:
       print 'Hello'
```

How will it ensure that I write a test case for my function by mocking the `DEFAULT_PATTERN`? I am basically checking if the pattern is present in the name i pass to the function.

Comment: Can you explain a little more precisely what is in your code and what you're trying to mock? It's unclear to me what your problem is or what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks @sytech. I have updated the questions. I am new to mocks. So just trying to find out the best way to write a test case for this checkName function. since the default pattern can change, i think we should mock it.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can get simpler and more reproducible than a one line constant declaration. What is it that you are wanting to replace with a mock, again?